# Possible to prevent a form reset from clearing readonly fields?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I use `<input type="reset">` to clear a form.

How can I prevent the reset function to clear `<input type="text" readonly>` or `<input type="text" disabled>` fields?

Comment: Make your own function

Comment: I've tried adding an .ignore class to the disabled fields, and using the following function $('input:text:not(".ignore")').val(''); but it still clears all fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
var resetForm = function(){ $(':text:not("[readonly],[disabled]")').val(''); }
//or this is probably better
//var resetForm = function(){ $('input,select,textarea').not('[readonly],[disabled],:button').val(''); }
</script>
<input value="test1" />
<input readonly value="test2"/>
<input disabled value="test3"/>
<input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="reset"/>
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/wuvilahobu/edit?html,output

**Update:**
Renamed function `reset` with `resetForm` because being reserved inside `<form>` it is not working.

Comment: This seems to work well, but when I put the input fields in <form></form>-tags it stops working. Any advice?

Comment: So simple. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

**Jquery**

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
  $("input").each(function(){

    if($(this).is('[readonly]') == false && $(this).is('[disabled]')== false)
    {
      $(this).val(null);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" readonly value="test">
<input type="text" value="okok">
<input type="text" value="disabled" disabled>
<button id="reset">
Reset
</button>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g64wva8d/)